# Finding all solutions in the Roth's theorem

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> **[Roth's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RothsTheorem.html).** For all algebraic  irrational  $\alpha$ 
>   $$\displaystyle \left \lvert \alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right \rvert < \frac{1}{q^{2 + \epsilon}}$$
>   with $\epsilon>0$,  has finitely many solutions.

How to find all solution for $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$ and $\epsilon=1$

I tried:

```
FindInstance[{Abs[Sqrt[2] - p/q] < 1/q^3, GCD[p, q] == 1}, {p,q}, Integers]
```

but there is an error message

[image]

Answer (score 5):

FindInstance does not handle GCD so well so leave it out and try:

```
FindInstance[{Abs[Sqrt[2] - p/q] < 1/q^3}, {p, q}, Integers, 5]


(*{{p -> 1, q -> 1}, {p -> 2, q -> 1}, {p -> 3, q -> 2}}*)
```

3 answers are better than none. You  can always do some post processing cleanup to weed out bad solutions but in this case there are none.

Comment: Hi;To the downvoter, what did I do wrong? I can try to fix it

Answer (score 5):

Consider the [convergents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents) and [semiconvergents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Semiconvergents) of your irrational number.

I have some bulky code to calculate semi-convergents.

```
SemiConvergents[v_, {1}] := Join[{0}, Convergents[v, 1]]
SemiConvergents[v_, 1] := Join[{0}, Convergents[v, 1]]

SemiConvergents[v_, {n_?OddQ}] :=
   Block[{a = Last[ContinuedFraction[v, n]], 
      c = Take[Convergents[v, n - 1], -2]},
      (Numerator[c[[1]]] + Range[0, a]*Numerator[c[[2]]])/
      (Denominator[c[[1]]] + Range[0, a]*Denominator[c[[2]]])
]

SemiConvergents[v_, {2}] := 
   Block[{a = ContinuedFraction[v, 2]}, Join[{Infinity}, a[[1]] + 1/Range[a[[2]]]]]
SemiConvergents[v_, 2] := 
   Block[{a = ContinuedFraction[v, 2]}, Join[{Infinity}, a[[1]] + 1/Range[a[[2]]]]]

SemiConvergents[v_, {n_?EvenQ}] :=
   Block[{a = Last[ContinuedFraction[v, n]], 
      c = Take[Convergents[v, n - 1], -2]},
      (Numerator[c[[1]]] + Range[0, a]*Numerator[c[[2]]])/
      (Denominator[c[[1]]] + Range[0, a]*Denominator[c[[2]]])
]
```

I use the following to calculate rational approximations to irrational `a`, subject to exponent `2+eps`.

```
RothAttempt[a_, eps_] :=
   Block[{r, kmax = 10},
      r = DeleteDuplicates[
             Flatten[Table[SemiConvergents[a, {k}], {k, 1, kmax}]]];
      Pick[r, Thread[Abs[a - r] < 1/Denominator[r]^(2 + eps)]]
]
```

I do not know how to chose `kmax` such that all solutions are found...